# Excel 0365 - Dependent, Repeatable Drop Down List Solution Difficulties

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with a list of Projects. Each Project will have one or more people involved and the role they are playing, so the excel sheet will display one row per person for the same project (duplicate project details, unique person/role). I am trying to create a dependent drop list so the user can select a role, then select a person from the list of individuals having that role. I'm stuck in a solution to create the same dependent drop down for each row because I'm using the "FILTER" function and that function will only look at ONE cell to filter down the list of matches:

Step 1: Create the Unique list of Roles, and Sort
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viDsh.png)

Step 2: Add list of Roles to Drop Down 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNSJP.png)

Step 3: Use FILTER to match the Person(s) to the Role that is selected in Drop Down 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZQQW.png)

Step 4: Use results from FILTER to populate Dependent Drop Down 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEwSi.png)

PROBLEM: When I select the Role drop down for the next Project row, the Dependent drop down displays the previous cell's results because the Filter formula can only look at one cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3y9.png)

What I need it to do, is to repeat the same process in the next row but the Dependent Drop Down list results should match the next Role drop down selection. Any advice?

Comment: Partial work around could be to use =FILTER(B2:B8,A2:A8=TAKE(TOCOL(H2:H100,1),-1,1)) . With this formula it would filter for last H column selection. Drawback is if you want to change I column for previous projects, you would need to delete latter H values to generate correct list

Comment: I've beaten up this issue pretty thoroughly and the best option I've come up with is to use a separate entry form (just a sheet with Data Validation cells to do the data entry) and then use a bit of VBA code to add the records.  You can use a set of FILTER functions to generate the datasets for each category and sub-category. Name the cell containing the FILTER function with the Category name and then use a # (spilled reference) in the Data Validation range.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my previous comment - I've got a test file that has State, County, City and Zips for about 95% of American Zip Codes. Each record has all 4 pieces of data. The FILTER function for "State" is: `=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSE({1},tblZips[State]),TRUE)),""). The Filter function for County is =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSE({1},tblZips[County]),(tblZips[State]=B2)))),"")` {B4 is the cell where the State is selected}, The FILTER functions for City is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSE({1},tblZips[City]),(tblZips[State]=B2)*(tblZips[County]=B3)))),"")
```

The FILTER function for the Zip is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSE({1},tblZips[Zip]),(tblZips[State]=B2)*(tblZips[County]=B3)*(tblZips[City]=B4)))),"")
```

I named the field with the "State" function 'State' and the Data Validation for the field where I select the State uses '=State#' as it's source.  I did the same for County, City and Zip. You now have a cascading dropdown model that only needs one source table for it's data.

Answer (score 0):

To generate repeating dependent drop down lists, as per your screenshots provided, you can use the XLOOKUP function, with a slightly modified lookup range.

First, clear out the headers and formulas currently in columns D and E. Then in cell C1, use the TRANSPOSE function to return the Unique Role list horizontally, as follows:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A8)))
```

The resulting array {Analyst, Architect, Engineer, Programmer} will spill across range C1:F1. Next, in cell C2, use the FILTER function to return the persons associated with the Analyst role, as follows:

```
=SORT(FILTER($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8=C1))
```

Note the use of absolute references ($ signs) for each range in the formula except C1, which is relative. Next, copy or drag the formula across from C2 to F2. The results returned will be four dynamic filtered lists for each of the four roles.

To create the first drop down list in column H of your Project table, select cells H2:H9, open the Data Validation dialog box and use the following range reference as the List Source:

```
=$C$1#
```

To create the second dependent drop down list in column I, select cells I2:I9, open the Data Validation dialog box and use the following formula as the List Source:

```
=XLOOKUP(H2,$C$1#,$C$2:$F$2)#
```

Again, note the use of absolute references for each range in the formula except H2. Also, note the use of the hashtag operator at the end of the XLOOKUP function, which is the key ingredient of this entire solution.

After clicking OK in the Data Validation dialog box, you may be prompted with the following message:

> The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?

Click Yes to proceed, and the dependent drop down will function as desired.

The overall results of your spreadsheet should now look something like this:

[dependent_drop_down.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lpbu.jpg)

Cheers!